# java - when debugging, if i have some writer, how can i get the file name+path it is writing to?

Tags: java, io, writer

When debugging, i'd like to, having come across a Writer, be able to tell where it is writing to.

A cursory inspection of the object yields little to work with on the file name/file path front.

Is there some way - either a method i can call on said Writer, or some field that i can inspect - that will let me know which file the Writer writes to?

Comment: ***Related Question:*** [Get file name from FileOutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4930111/597657)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, if you can dig down to a file descriptor number, you can examine /proc/*pid*/fd/*fdnum* to see what file or socket it references.

On Windows, if you can dig down to a file handle, you can use a tool like [Sys Internals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to trace the handle to a physical file.

On a Darwin/BSD system you would use opensnoop.