# how to know file name with extension from Remote FileInputStream in java

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream, fileutils

hi i have a FileInputStream which is pointing remote file in the server.

how to know the filename and its extension which is pointed by this stream.

if i want to write the remote file in my local computer, i have to know the file name and its extension that's what i want to know

Comment: what do you actually need , i mean list of present files?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930111/get-file-name-from-fileoutputstream ? i.e. you can only try to use reflection, but you're better off changing the way your code works, so that it can get the filename from the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

There are no public methods that return the `File`, `Path` or `String` from `FileInputStream`.

The best workaround is to wrap `FileInputStream`, store `File` in the wrapper class and implement `getFile()` method.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if(file.isDirectory())
       {
           File f=file.listFiles();
            for(File name : f)
                pirnt(name.getName());

}
```