# How do I turn a FileOutputStream to a File (Java)?

Tags: java, file, io, data-conversion, fileoutputstream

I create a file using a `FileOutputStream()`, and after creating it I want to check if that file exists.

I have tried to see if there is something like `File.exists()` for it, I also looked at [get file name from fileoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930111/get-file-name-from-fileoutputstream) but that solves how to get the filename, which is not my question. So I need a way to turn the `FileOutputStream()` to a `File()`.

Comment: How did you create the `FileOutputStream`?

Answer (score -1):

A FileOutputSteam takes either a File as an argument or a filename (which will be converted to a file by the constructor).

If you have a reference to the file, file.exists() should return true, see kotlin code example below:

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val file = File.createTempFile("foo",".txt")
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(1)

        println("assert tmpfile exists: ${file.exists()}")
    }
```

Comment: Uhh... That's _Kotlin_, I'm looking for a solution for _Java_...

Comment: The constructor arguments are the same in Java because FileOutputStream is a Java class, even in kotlin

Answer (score -3):

You can instantiate the OutputStream using a Path object.
Here's a couple of ways

Using Files:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/a/b/c");
try(OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(path)) {
  Files.exists(path);
}
```

Using FileOutputStream:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/a/b/c");
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile())) {
  path.toFile().exists();
}
```

Comment: that was not the question.